# Flash Lite 2 Split Image

Tags: image, actionscript-2, movieclip, flashlite

Can flash lite 2(as2) split an image in to multiple movie clips? For example, get an image and split it in half to to mc's.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a way that probably does what you want. If you just need to make it look like the image is split, you can make two copies of it and apply dynamic masks, but masks tend to be a bit CPU intensive for mobiles, so that might not suit your needs. It would perform better to split the bitmap at author-time, and just keep the two halves stuck together until you need them apart (if that's an option).

There aren't any other good options though, as Flash Lite 2 doesn't have any of the bitmap-related features you find in AS3.